# AppleTV sees my Mac Mini but It can't access its information

Tags: macos, itunes, appletv, streaming

I have the latest version of the Mac Mini with the updated software on my Apple TV 2. It can see my Mac Mini but when it try to access it's information with iTunes open I says it is loading but eventually errors out. I can ping successfully from my Mac Mini to the Apple TV. I have the latest version of iTunes.

My MacBook Pro and Mac Pro can be accessed successfully on the Apple TV. All three are running Lion with the latest updates.

The Mac Mini did at one time work on the Apple TV. The firewall is off on the Mac Mini.

I went through the steps [listed here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2972) without any success.

Any suggestions to get the Mac Mini and Apple TV to work again would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple Discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2612084?start=0&tstart=0):

> In iTunes, Edit>Preferences>Sharing>Share my library on my local
> network.
> I saw this was unchecked, and checked it.

And maybe more meaningful:

> "Once Home Sharing has been turned on, Apple TV will automatically
> find iTunes libraries on your local network that have Home Sharing
> turned on using the account name you entered. The shared libraries
> will appear in Computers on the main menu of Apple TV."
>
> The implication is that a "shared library" must exist on the computer
> that has Home Sharing turned on in order to be found.

And to conclude:

> First things first, unplug the ethernet cable from your apple TV and
> check your settings under **Setting > General > Network**. Note the IP
> address.
>
> Secondly, plug the ethernet cable back in and check your
> settings. **Setting > General > Network** - are they the same or totally
> different? If they are different you most likely have an issue where
> your iTunes Homeshared Library is running off of a different IP
> Address than your Apple TV.

Also, make sure you have your ports right!